# Running Redhawk SDR with Wind River VxWorks 7.+

Tags: vxworks, redhawksdr

Can the Redhawk SDR be run on top of Wind River's VxWorks 7.0 RTOS?
It appears it can run under Linux, but what about VxWorks?

Answer (score 1):

REDHAWK only supports CentOS 6 and 7.

If you would like to try build from source, you will need to compile VxWorks versions of the dependencies, the latest are listed in Appendix B of the REDHAWK manual at: http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainap2.html#x22-511000B